# Running script ... message stays there on some systems/browsers

Tags: google-apps-script

One of our users is having trouble executing one of ours apps. Whenever they access the script, the "Running script  Dismiss" message stays there for a seemingly infinite time.

Are there some plugins in browsers which stop google app script from working correctly? They have tried Firefox on linux and Firefox and Chrome on Mac.

The script can be accessed via this template - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al5WvYyk0zzmdDNLeEcxWHZJX042dS0taXJPNXpJMHc , a tool menu will appear named OntoMaton. All four actions in this menu, including the trivial "About" item, are failing/hanging for the user.

Comment: Although you've given the link to the doc, other users will not have access to the script. The reason why it hangs depends on what you've coded in those functions. Can you provide code samples of what is in one of those functions.

Comment: Well the issue is that it works on every other machine we've tried it on. This case is an outlier and we're trying to figure out why. The code for the most simple script (which also doesn't work on his machine) is here. https://github.com/ISA-tools/OntoMaton/blob/master/About.js

Answer (score 1):

We've discovered that the issue is the shared doc does not ask for permission to run on the users machine, therefore the script is unable to run but there should be a warning message for this.

I asked the user to install the app script from the gallery directly then everything worked for them.