# Google Script oAuth + Odesk API

Tags: api, oauth, google-apps-script, google-oauth, api-key

**Hi, I've been using oDesk API for long time but now I need authorization to get some data but I couldn't figure it out. Here is the code I'm using and getting oAuth error. Your help would be very useful if you know something.**

```
function debug() {
    var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService("odeskapi");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.odesk.com/api/auth/v1/oauth/token/request");
    oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.odesk.com/api/auth/v1/oauth/token/access");
    oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.odesk.com/services/api/auth");

    var options = {
        "method" : "GET",
        "oAuthServiceName" : "odeskapi",
        "oAuthUseToken" : "always"
    };

    var request = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.odesk.com/api/profiles/v1/search/jobs.json", options);
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? That is very important to share - otherwise we will have to register for oDesk API to get the keys and run this code!

Comment: Google just says "OAuth Error". No more details. Even I do not know how to check where it stumbles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
oAuthConfig.setMethod("post");
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! The error gone but now it just shows "Running script (Dismiss)". I tried to remove "method: GET" from "options" but it didn't help. Any guesses?

Comment: Do you set the permissions of your oDesk API?

https://www.odesk.com/services/api/keys
`Permissions: All permissions`

Comment: Yep!

"Project type: Web", "Callback URL: google.com", "Auth type: OAuth 1.0", "API usage: 11-100", "Issued: 2013-09-19 08:54:18", "Status: Active", "Permissions: All permissions"

Comment: You may need to re-auth your GAS script, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214100/running-script-message-stays-there-on-some-systems-browsers

Try this:

    1. use a wrong ConsumerKey, run debug();
    2. use the correct ConsumerKey, rerun and auth the permissions

Comment: Thank you guys! I just had to run debug() function from script editor first. It asked to confirm authorization and then I can use the function directly from spreadsheet. Thanks again for your suggestions!